# Absolute convergence of the Fourier series of a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function on the circle

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-series

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function which is $2\pi$-periodic. Define the Fourier coefficients of $f$:
> $$C = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \, dx, \ A_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \cos(nx) \, dx, \ B_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \sin(nx) \, dx.$$
> Then $$f(x) = C + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n \cos(nx) + B_n \sin(nx)),$$ and the series above converges absolutely.

I am trying to understand why the fact stated above is true. I know that there are lots of references on Fourier series, and even questions on this site related to this, but they are all in various levels of generality and I got a bit lost searching through all of them. So, my question is the following: what would be the simplest way to prove this fact "from scratch", or give me a pointer to some reference where that is done?

You can of course assume all the basic facts of integration theory (either Riemann or Lebesgue). You can also assume the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma (for Riemann integrable functions), since I am also already comfortable with that result.

Edit: I changed the assumption on $f$ from differentiable to continuously differentiable, as discussed in the comments.

Comment: I think that differentiable is not sufficient. Assuming that $f$ is continuous and piecewise $\mathcal{C}^1$ is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, if that is true I am okay with assuming that $f$ is $C^1$. That was actually my original assumption but from my search I thought that differentiability would be enough.

Comment: If $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, the exponential Fourier coefficients satisfy $c_n(f')= 2i \pi nT c_n(f)$ (integration by parts). This helps to prove the normal convergence of the Fourier series of $f$. View https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Fourier Théorème de convergence normale de Dirichlet (I did not find a reference in english).

Comment: Thank you! In that link they prove that the series of the Fourier coefficients converges absolutely, how does that imply the normal convergence of the Fourier series? 
Also in that same proof, they show first that the series of the Fourier coefficients of $f'$ converges (using the Bessel inequality), and then apply that to show that the series of Fourier coefficients of $f$ converges. Why can't we just apply the same argument directly to $f$ without going through $f'$ first?

Comment: View https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995735/absolute-convergence-of-the-fourier-series?rq=1

Comment: The convergence of the series $\sum_n |c_n(f)|^2$ does not imply the convergence of the series $\sum_n |c_n(f)|$, but the convergence of the series $\sum_n n^2|c_n(f)|^2$ does.

Comment: You're right, I completely missed the square in the sum. Thank you a lot for your help, but I still have a further question: we have shown that the series converges absolutely, but how do we show that the sum is equal to $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, the exponential Fourier coefficients satisfy $c_n(f') = 2i\pi n c_n(f)$ (integration by parts). This helps to prove the convergence of the series $\sum_n |c_n(f)|$, i.e. the normal convergence of the Fourier series of $f$. View fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Fourier Théorème de convergence normale de Dirichlet (I did not find a reference in english).

Because of the normal convergence, when computing the Fourier coefficients of the sum of the Fourier series, one may switch the sum and the integral. One gets that the Fourier coefficients of the sum are the same as those of $f$.

By continuity of $f$ and injectivity of the map $f \mapsto (c_n(f))_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ from $L^1_{2\pi}$ to $c_0(\mathbb{Z})$, one deduces that the sum is $f$.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with what you write and I would have argued similarly. However, here $f$ is only differentiable so you cannot integrate by parts. I wonder whether this is really wanted or if the C^1 case would be enough. EDIT: I now see that this has been discussed in comments. I agree with you that the differentiability assumption alone might be insufficient.

Comment: Finally, a standard English reference for the convergence of Fourier serier is the book of Yitzak Katznelson, chapter II: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/an-introduction-to-harmonic-analysis/67C4CE356E7420BA17F3F1337291EF82

Comment: How would you show the injectivity of the Fourier coefficients map? Also, I suppose we also need the continuity of the sum of the Fourier series of $f$ right? Although it follows easily from what has been done, since the Fourier series converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: @J.C. It is a classical theorem. If a continuous periodic function is such that its Fourier coefficients are all null, then it is orthogonal to all trigonometric polynomial (by linearity), hence to all continuous functions (by density), hence it is orthogonal to itself, so it is null.